# How to prove or disprove $ |r'(a)| \leq c_1 \sup_{x \in [a-1/2,a+1/2]} |r(x)|$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, rational-functions

Let $ A  = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 1 \\ 0 & a
    \end{bmatrix}$ be a Jordan matrix with $ -1 < a < 1 $.

Let $r(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ be an irreducible rational function, where $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are polynomials of degree $k$ with **real coefficients**, and $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are not zero on the interval $E = \{v^\top Av | v \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|v\| = 1\} = [a-1/2, a+1/2] $.

**My problem is finding a positive number $c$ (possibly depends on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}\notag
        \|r(A)\|_2 \leq c \sup_{x \in E} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}**

I have obtained
\begin{equation}\notag
        r(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
            r(a) & r'(a) \\ 0 & r(a)
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $\|r(A)\|_2 \leq \sqrt{2}\|r(A)\|_1 = \sqrt{2}(|r(a)| + |r'(a)|)$. Thus **I guess that there may exist a positive number $c_1$ (possibly depends on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}\notag
        |r'(a)|  \leq c_1 \sup_{x \in E} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}**
However, I don't know how to prove or disprove this conjecture.

Comment: Are the constants allowed to depend on $a$?

Comment: For polynomials this is a version of the *Markov brothers inequality*. A rough version is easy to deduce from the fact that linear maps on finite dimensional spaces are continuous.

Comment: I just found this article https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/acta/2017/0219/0001/ACTA-2017-0219-0001-a003.pdf

Comment: @FedorPetrov The constant is allowed to depend on $a$ and $k$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will read [this paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/acta/2017/0219/0001/ACTA-2017-0219-0001-a003.pdf) seriously

Comment: I now feel that E should not be $[-1,1]$, but should be $\{v^\top A v | \|v\| = 1, v \in \mathbb{R}^2 \} = [a-1/2, a+ 1/2]$.

Comment: The $|r'(a)| \leq sup_{x \in E} |r'(x)| \leq c_1 sup_{x \in E} |r(x)| $ in the conjecture should be changed to $|r'(a)| \leq c_1 sup_{x \in E} |r(x)| $, where $E = \{v^\top Av | v \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|v\| = 1\} = [a-1/2, a+1/2] $.

Comment: Well, what if $r(x)=1/(x^2+\varepsilon^2)$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov For $r(x)$, the degree of numerator $p(x)$ and denominator $q(x)$ must be the same.

Comment: Well, replace the numerator to $x^2+1$